# Unable to return List<FileInfo> object

Tags: c#, list, collections, directoryinfo, system.io.fileinfo

I am trying to return a list of type FileInfo by searching an arbitrary directory recursively. However, in my main() method, when I check to see the count of FoundFiles, it is 0 meaning I returned an empty object. See Code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class FindExtensions
{  
    private static List<FileInfo> SearchFileSystem(DirectoryInfo DirInfo, List<FileInfo> FileList)
    {
        List<FileInfo> FileInfoList = new List<FileInfo>();
        try
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo SubdirInfo in DirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                SearchFileSystem(SubdirInfo, FileList);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // do some stuff
        }
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo File in DirInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                FileInfoList.Add(File);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // do some stuff
        }


        foreach (FileInfo f in FileInfoList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
        }

        return FileInfoList;

    }

    static void Main()
    {

        DirectoryInfo dir_info = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\<whatever>");
        List<FileInfo> file_list = new List<FileInfo>();

        List<FileInfo> FoundFiles = SearchFileSystem(dir_info, file_list);

        Console.WriteLine("Count is: " + FoundFiles.Count);

        //^^^^ this returns 0...why is it empty?

        Console.WriteLine("This is the debug mode. Press key to restart");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I added a for loop in the SearchFileSystem method to check the contents of FileInfoList before I return it, and it will contain files. However, it contains nothing in main. I'm new to the nuances of C#, so apologies if this is quite easy.

Also, it is worth noting that if I use type List with string instead of FileInfo, this works just fine. Hoping to use a List of type FileInfo if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `GetFiles()` method and let it do the work for you

```
static void Main()
{

    DirectoryInfo dir_info = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\<whatever>");
    List<FileInfo> file_list = new List<FileInfo>();

    //This will add all the files in all directories. You can customize the search from here as well.
    file_list.AddRange(dir_info.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    Console.WriteLine("Count is: " + file_list.Count);

    //^^^^ this returns 0...why is it empty?

    Console.WriteLine("This is the debug mode. Press key to restart");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But! In answer to your question, you are calling `List<FileInfo> FoundFiles = new List<FileInfo>();` every time you call `SearchFileSystem(...)`. Then you call the method recursively but don't use any of the results from there.

If you want to use your existing code, here are the necessary changes I'd make:

```
private static void SearchFileSystem(DirectoryInfo DirInfo, List<FileInfo> FileList)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DirectoryInfo SubdirInfo in DirInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            SearchFileSystem(SubdirInfo, FileList);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    //Since we are passing in FileList, let's use it instead of a new list.
    try
    {
        foreach (FileInfo File in DirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            FileList.Add(File);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // do some stuff
    }


    foreach (FileInfo f in FileList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
    }
}

static void Main()
{

    DirectoryInfo dir_info = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\<whatever>");
    List<FileInfo> file_list = new List<FileInfo>();

    SearchFileSystem(dir_info, file_list);

    Console.WriteLine("Count is: " + FoundFiles.Count);

    //^^^^ this returns 0...why is it empty?

    Console.WriteLine("This is the debug mode. Press key to restart");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I should have stated it above, but I have to account for files that the user running the program will have unauthorized access to. Hence, the recursive strategy. I'll Use the AddRange method though.

Comment: @PiyushParashar Objects are defaulted to pass by reference in C#. Only with structs do you need to explicitly state that you passing by ref or out. It's not a bad idea for objects as well because it states intention but for very simplistic code like this I usually skip.

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding the results from recursive calls. So ideally you are getting the results from only the last directory which may not have some files.. Try this:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo SubdirInfo in DirInfo.GetDirectories())
            {
                FileInfoList.AddRange(SearchFileSystem(SubdirInfo, FileList));
            }
```

Comment: Good call. I wasn't looking at where I was storing the data. Making my List a global variable did the trick for now.